# How to Use Same SQL Connection String After Server Name Change?

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

We have a set of over 10,000 Excel files that were all created from a template (don't ask). They all use the same connection string to connect to a SQL Server database. Now the name of the server is changing and there is no simple way to globally replace it in the connection strings of all 10,000+ files. Is there any way to keep the same connection string and still have the files be able to connect?

The server name is changing from "ABCNT3" to "ABCSQL16P1", so I need a way for the line "Data Source = ABCNT3" to still connect to ABCSQL16P1. Really hoping it's possible.

Comment: Holy cow that sounds like a really horrible thing to do. You could use DNS to handle this.

Comment: Seconding the DNS alias (assuming the server ABCNT3 no longer exists)

Comment: Yes, it is horrible, and I strongly advised against using Excel the way they're using it, but did they listen?

Comment: Using Excel as the front end to an application is just a bad idea on so many levels. I get it, I am preaching to the choir here but wow. Maybe now they will listen?

Comment: Adding that to get DNS to handle it, you'd need to ask your network team to add a C name entry. It will reroute all traffic sent to "ABCNT3" to "ABCSQL16P1".

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: This is a little hackish, which will make it difficult for another person to maintain this after you. However, considering your (already) bad situation, this will solve your current problem until you can determine a more-permanent solution.

If you don't already have SQL tools installed, you will need "SQL Server Configuration Manager".  I installed it as part of admin tools for SQL 2017 (SSMS).
Run it from the machine with all of your Excel files.

Once it opens, pick the last one from the list, named "SQL Native Client ##.# Configuration". Expand it and choose "Aliases". 
Create New.
Alias name = "ABCNT3", Server="ABCSQL16P1".

Your Excel will believe that the new server is the old server. It is pretty seamless.